# Efficiently find Delaunay Triangulation face, which a given point lies on

Tags: c#, math, computational-geometry, delaunay

Given a Delaunay Triangulation of a point set, how should I index my triangulation to do quick point localization?

I'm currently looping over all the triangles. For each triangle, I'm checking if the given point is within triangle's bounding rectangle. If it is, I then check the triangle using geometry equations.

This is slow. Any ideas of how to make this search more efficient?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are talking about, let alone what your question is.  Post some code, and don't assume that we know the specifics of your problem, based only the very general reference to an algorithm in your title.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Seems pretty clear to me: Given a Delaunay Triangulation of a point set, how do you do index your triangulation to do quick point localization?

Comment: @TimothyShields If the question were as clear as your comment, I wouldn't have a problem with it and I suspect it would already have some answers.  If you're sure that is what is being asked, then I encourage you to edit it for clarity.

Comment: @TimothyShields Thanks,I couldn't have phrased it any better.

Comment: Quad tree or BSP perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Mission accomplished, that's the way I ended up doing it:

1) Check if the point lies within triangle bounding rectangle.

2) Assign the point as the start of a horizontal line, ending at max width.

3) Check intersections from the triangles found in (1) with the line from (2).

4) If triangle intersect, check how many times the horizontal line intersect with the triangle.

5) If intersects 1 time, means point in triangle. Else, not in triangle.

Reference:

[Fast generation of points inside triangulated objects obtained by cross-sectional contours](http://www.mlahanas.de/CompGeom/Point_in_Poly.htm)

Comment: This does not reduce the efficiency of the algorithm in the asymptotic sense: checking against all bounding boxes is still `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

Ranging from quick and practical to theoretically robust, here are three approaches you could use:

- Construct a regular grid where each cell contains a list of triangles that intersect it. Given a query point, in constant time determine the cell that contains it, then compare your query point against only those triangles that are in that cell's list.
- Construct a quadtree where each leaf cell contains the triangles that intersect it. Localizing the query point to a quadtree leaf takes logtime, but this can be more efficient in both speed and memory overall.
- Sweep a horizontal line down across all the triangles. Points in your point sets correspond to events. At each event, some triangles begin intersecting the sweepline, and other triangles stop intersecting the sweepline. You can use an immutable (aka persistent) sorted map data structure to efficiently represent this. `map<double, sweepstate>`, where the key is the y-intercept of the sweepline at an event and `sweepstate` is a sorted list of line segment pairs (corresponding to the left and right sides of triangles). Given a query point, you first use its y value to lookup a `sweepstate`, and then you do a single trapezoid containment test. (Two horizontal sweeplines and two line segments between them form a trapezoid.)

Comment: I actually like the first approach of the equal cells and saving the intersecting triangles, I've been reading about "Walking through" the triangulation using nearest neighbor, although I cant seem to fully understand the way it works yet. If nothing else found, I'd probably use your first approach :)

Comment: @Elia I start with the first approach as well. Only go down the list to more complicated approaches if the first approach proves to be too slow. It could also have difficulty with point sets in which some areas are very sparse and other areas are very dense.

Comment: If you're interested, I've just posted an answer of how things ended up.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is a hierarchical tree, I.e. dendogram or hierarchical cluster. For example use the euklidian distance:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering.  Or you can use a metric tree.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to solve this point location problem is the efficient [Trapezoidal Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location#Trapezoidal_decomposition). It reduces the query time to `O(Log(N))` per point, after `O(N.Log(N))` preprocessing time, using `O(N)` space.

It could also be that the distribution of your query points allows alternative/simpler approaches.

Comment: @Phpdna: Is assume you mean dendogram. I don't see ant connection. The one is a clustering method, the other an efficient geometric search data structure.

Comment: What is the complexity of a query in an Euclidean dendogram ? [The trapezoidal decomposition is time- and space- optimal in the asymptotic sense.]

Comment: Er, sorry, this question is not about nearest neighbors search, it's about point location in a triangulation.

Comment: Can you give me a pointer to a description of the search algorithm ?

Comment: I am referring to the standard way to qualify algorithm complexity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity).

Comment: Can you give me a pointer to a description of the search algorithm ?

Comment: Your own words: nearest neighbors search. I'd like to see a description of the algorithm (research paper or tutorial site, preferably with complexity analysis). Never seen that done with a dendogram.

Comment: I have put a link in my answer. You'd better have looked at it rather than downvoting.